# Sequel select columns with same names results removing columns

Tags: sql, ruby, sequel

I am joining different tables which have columns with same names. When I first tried to select them, I came into the `ambiguous column name` error, i.e. there were columns with same names. Therefore, I made an explicit selection of columns, but now I get less columns than I requested.

```rb
  response = DB[:courses].select(Sequel[:courses][:id], Sequel[:courses][:title], Sequel[:courses][:headline], Sequel[:courses][:description], Sequel[:courses][:slug], Sequel[:courses][:avg_duration], Sequel[:courses][:points], Sequel[:courses][:intro_video_url], Sequel[:courses][:background_color], Sequel[:courses][:views], Sequel[:courses][:certificate_option], Sequel[:courses][:url], Sequel[:courses][:is_active], Sequel[:courses][:num_subscribers], Sequel[:courses][:num_reviews], Sequel[:courses][:num_finished], Sequel[:courses][:avg_rating], Sequel[:courses][:avg_rating_recent], Sequel[:locales][:title], Sequel[:locales][:english_title], Sequel[:courses][:has_caption], Sequel[:courses][:is_paid], Sequel[:courses][:price], Sequel[:courses][:price_discount], Sequel[:courses][:currency], Sequel[:instructors][:headline], Sequel[:instructors][:name], Sequel[:instructors][:slug], Sequel[:instructors][:image], Sequel[:instructors][:initials], Sequel[:instructors][:url], Sequel[:instructors][:origin_id], Sequel[:courses][:image_preview], Sequel[:courses][:image_view], Sequel[:difficulties][:name], Sequel[:course_types][:name], Sequel[:origins][:image_url], Sequel[:origins][:name], Sequel[:origins][:url_about])
    .join(:locales, id: Sequel[:courses][:locale_id])
    .join(:instructors, id: Sequel[:courses][:instructor_id])
    .join(:origins, id: Sequel[:courses][:origin_id])
    .join(:difficulties, id: Sequel[:courses][:difficulty_id])
    .join(:course_types, id: Sequel[:courses][:course_type_id])
    .where(Sequel.ilike(Sequel[:courses][:title], "%#{title}%")).where( is_paid: is_paid).limit(count).offset(count * (page - 1))
```

I expected to get 38 columns, but I get 32. I tried to explicitly get only columns (`select.columns`) or get via map (`select.map`), however the result is same. When I do this request natively in SQLite prompt, it returns exact 38 columns. I also tried to do queries with gem `sqlite3`, however the same prompt results in only 32 columns.

How can I get all columns without making any sacrifices? Can I rename names while making a selection or is there any other solution?

Comment: *Can I rename names while making a selection or is there any other solution?* Yes you can alias columns in the select statement [Docs](https://github.com/jeremyevans/sequel#expression-aliases-)

Answer (score 0):

First you need to give each table an alias. Then when you write your select statement prepend each column you are selecting with the table alias like `alias.column_name`.